# Why is my code stopping prematurely? what have i done wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm just starting so I'm trying to write a program which determine if a number is positive or negative.

```
#include <iostream>;

int step_function(int x) {
    
    int result = 0; 
    
    if (x > 0) 
        result = 1;
    else if (x < 0) 
        result = -1;
    else 
        result = 0;

    return result;
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int num;
    
    cout<< "please enter number : ";
    cin >> num;
    
    int a = step_function(num); 
    
    if (a == 1) 
        printf("%d is positive", num);
    else if (a == -1) 
        printf("%d is negative", num);
    else 
        printf(" it is zero");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving the program, what output are you expecting, and what output do you see? Please be very specific, and please edit your question with this information.

Comment: `#include <iostream>;` is obviously wrong

Comment: you can replace `printf` with `cout`

Comment: I can't reproduce any problems, please show a [mre] that actually causes an error. Please hardcode an example input  (`num = ...`) to help us reproduce the problem. And please be more precise about what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things you should do:

- First things first you should get yourself a [Good Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for `C++`.
- Second thing is read why [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is a bad idea.
- Lastly here is your code fixed. You needed to remove the semicolon as well as removing the `printf()`. I also removed the `using namespace std;` which made it more readable.

```
#include <iostream>

int step_function(int); //Function prototype

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "please enter number : ";
    std::cin >> num;
    int a = step_function(num);
    if (a == 1)
        std::cout << num << " is postive"; 
    else if (a == -1)
        std::cout << num << " is negative";
    else std::cout <<" it is zero";

    return 0;
}


int step_function(int x) 
{
    int result = 0;
    if (x > 0) result = 1;
    else if (x < 0) result = -1;
    else result = 0;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use semicolon after `#include <iostream>`.
I think for C++ `cout` is more standard whereas `printf` is from C.
You can also include printing of the text in the `step_function`. Also, it's better to use braces {} after `if` and `else` statements for clarity especially if the code becomes complex.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void step_function(int x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        cout << x << " is positive" << endl;
    }
    else if (x < 0) {
        cout << x << " is negative" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "it is zero" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    cout<< "please enter number : ";
    cin >> num;

    step_function(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agree with most of the commentary, but... printing directly in `step_function` and returning nothing reduces the usability of `step_function` to cases where you merely want to print. Asker's version is better in my opinion.